# Add IpRange value to input dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add an input field the user can enter/modify an IP Address in the format 198.162.0.0/45 representing a range from 198.162.0.0 - 198.162.0.45

what I have almost works but its not allowing the complete correct format. If I enter any of the following it works fine.
198/45, 198.168, or 198.168.0.45

but as soon as I try to add
198.168.0/24 or 198.168.0.0/24

I wanted to be able to add 198.168.0.0/24 without having to breakup the fields but if I have to I can.

it gets a scripting error when my dynamic element is appended to the div tag containing the input fields.

basically my setup is this, empty div tag I will append the following to. The newIpRange comes in as a string such as 198.168.0.0/24
EDIT with test html that produces the issue

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test IP</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function onload(range){

var e = document.getElementById("_main");
e.innerHTML = getTag(range);

}

function getTag(range){
return "<div class='input-append'  ><input  type='text' value='" + range + "' ></input><div>";
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="onload(198.168.1.0/24);">
<div id="_main" >

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

what would be causing this? of interest to me really is why does it give the error in some cases, not others

Here is the Error I'm getting from the script when I appent this line: SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'

Comment: Can you include the Javascript code you're using the generate the html?

Comment: The syntax you're using is poorly chosen -- it's already used for [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation). For instance, `192.168.0.0/16` already represents the range `192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255`.

Comment: thanks for the link. I had a misunderstanding on that part. But that is still the notation I need to use to meet my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a little time with the sample I made I finally came to the realization, its how javascript is parsing the values.

in the case of 10.12/24 its evaluating it as a number with a division
as soon as I add the extra period in there it can no longer evaluate it as a number, to solve that putting it in a string literal cleans everything up!

to fix this I put the ipcallback into a pair of single quotes to tell javascript its a string

```
<script>
</head>
<body onload="onload('198.168.1.0/24');">
<div id="_main" >
```